# Gradient effect with Chart.js and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I want to make my chart a bit prettier and found the Gradient effect but how can i proper implement this in my Angular project ? I found some similar thing on the Web but I always get `ERROR TypeError: this.canvas is undefined` no matter how I Init the DOM element. can someone help me with this problem? PS I'm using the ng2-charts package.

my ViewChild and my Init:

```
    @ViewChild("canvas") canvas: ElementRef;
  lineChartColors;


  ngAfterContentInit() {
      const domCanvasAccess = this.canvas.nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement;
      const gradientColor = domCanvasAccess.getContext('2d').createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
      gradientColor.addColorStop(0, 'green');
      gradientColor.addColorStop(1, 'white');
      this.lineChartColors = [
        {
          backgroundColor: gradientColor,
          borderColor: "black",
        }
      ];
  }
```

for the rest here is a **StackBiltz**:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uop8dm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** This is how I do it without *ng2-charts*,

I create the Chart as explained on the charts.js documentation :

```
 this.chart =  new Chart(
        "canvas",
        {...
        }
```

And then, after that, I add the gradient

```
const ctx = this.chart.ctx;
const height = this.chart.height;
const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height);
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(128, 182, 244, 0.6)");
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)");
this.chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = gradient;
```

Comment: but this doesn't implements ng2-charts this is just Chart.js. I wanted to know about the implementation of the Gradience effect in the ng2-chart expansion.

Comment: How to add angles to it? 
have this CSS linear-gradient(135deg, #FBCF33 0%, #F53939 90%);